# How to show a div when another div is clicked?

Tags: jquery, css, html, tumblr

The question is pretty simple really and I know there must be an obvious answer out there. I have a div id called `#pagebox` and I want it to display when `#about` is clicked on.

Thank you; I would include HTML and CSS but I don't believe it would be of much help.

Comment: u want to hide `#pagebox` first and den to display when clicked on `#about`??

Comment: jQuery has awesome docs that you can pretty much copy and paste until you start to learn the API by heart.  I'd try that before asking as it'd be a lot quicker than waiting for answers. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UNNu8/)

This is really all you need:

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $('#pagebox').show();
});
```

---

**Notes:**

You should put your code inside a document ready function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //above code goes here
});
```

This solution uses jQuery, so you must include a reference to the jQuery library in the document head tags, like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If the code does not exist in the DOM originally but is injected, either via javascript/jQuery or via AJAX, then you must should use this format:

```
$('#about').on('click', function(){
    $('#pagebox').show();
});
```

---

Sources/References:

[Alex Garret's 200 10-min beginner videos about jQuery (FREE)](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32)
[W3School's excellent jQuery selector reference chart](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)
[More from Alex Garret (also free)](http://phpacademy.org)

Comment: Thank you for the in depth reply! So I've used `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#about').on('click', function(){
    $('#pagebox').show();
});
</script>` 
and
`#pagebox{
        z-index:99;
        background-color:white;
        position:fixed;
        width:700px;
        margin-left:-350px;
        margin-top:-300px;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        height:600px;
        visibility:hidden;
        }`
but it still isn't working for some reason?

Comment: Very difficult to solve just from code in the comment. I suggest that you close this question (select a best answer) and create a new question with the revised code. A new question will also garner more views, more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#about").on("click", function(){
    $("#pagebox").show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's still not working. I've used `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$("#about").on("click", function(){
    $("#pagebox").show();
});
</script>`
and
`<div id="about"><a href="http://www.hugowolfdesigns.tumblr.com/about" class = "navlink">About</a></div>`
Also is it worth mentioning that this is for Tumblr?

Comment: If this pagebox show script works, I would like to get rid of the link for the About div

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$("#about").on("click", function(){
    $("#pagebox").css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this, with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#about").click(function(){
        $("#pagebox").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#about").click(function(){
    $("#pagebox").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without anything else to look at, I'd use:

```
$('#about').on('click', function(){
    $('#pagebox').toggle();
});
```

Usually I store element collections in a variable, depending on frequency of use, to save dipping into the DOM more than necessary.

Toggle allows the the element, #about, to alternately show/hide the #pagebox.